# Ubuntu: reading local user env variable in service

Tags: services, environment-variables

I have a Linux service running on my ubuntu machine. in this machine, I need to read proxy setting environment variables ( like https_proxy, http_proxy, no_proxy, etc) values for the currently logged-in user.

when I am trying to read https_proxy from my service code, it is being printed as an empty string but when I am printing from the terminal the values are correct.

I think the service is not able to read it because it is running as root. Is there any way that can help in reading local user env variables from a service running with root privilege?

Comment: What service and variables?

Comment: it is my own service and trying to read proxy env variables.

Comment: *Users* don't have environments as such - they're a property of *processes*. You *might* be able to read a logged-in user's current environment by finding the PID of a process in their session then reading `/proc/<PID>/environ`, perhaps using `sudo -u <user>` to provide read access.

Comment: Have your user write the variables and their values into a file whenever you change them (automate this). Have your service read this file. Use `/run/local_env`, perhaps?

Comment: @steeldriver the process file at /proc/<pID>/environ does not have http_proxy/https_proxy/no_proxy ... am i missing something here?